# TextView repositions when text is entered in EditText [XML]

Tags: android, xml, layout, move

I have a simple table layout that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnSqa.jpg

My problem is that whenever I type text into the Artist, Venue or Comments EditText boxes, once the text string is in line vertically with the start of the Date TextView, the TextView start position moves position to stay in line with the string of characters; like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm2jA.jpg

I'm not sure if the Button is trying to match its end point to the string of characters or if the TextView is trying to match its start point to the string of characters but either way somethings not right.

Can anyone give me some insight as to what is happening here?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the XML file for the page shown:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/titleBar"
        android:id="@+id/addTitle"
        android:text="@string/add"          />

   <TableLayout
        style="@style/my_table"
        android:id="@+id/addTable"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addTitle">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                style="@style/largeText"
                android:text="@string/artistName"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <EditText
                style="@style/tableEditText"
                android:id="@+id/editName"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                style="@style/largeText"
                android:text="@string/venue"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <EditText
                style="@style/tableEditText"
                android:id="@+id/editVenue"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                style="@style/largeText"
                android:text="@string/date"/>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <Button
               android:background="@android:color/transparent"
               android:drawableRight="@drawable/event_1"
               android:id="@+id/setDateButton"/>
           <TextView
               style="@style/tableEditText"
               android:layout_weight="3"
               android:layout_width="200dp"
               android:id="@+id/editDate"/>
       </TableRow>

       <TableRow>
            <TextView
                style="@style/largeText"
                android:text="@string/comments"/>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
            <EditText
                style="@style/tableEditText"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3"
                android:id="@+id/editComments"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/add"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="largeText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="largeText2">
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/bgOrange</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/nearBlack</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="titleBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:padding">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/headingOrange</item>
    </style>

    <style name="my_table">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">15sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="tableEditText">
        <item name="android:inputType">textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions|textAutoComplete</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/bgOrange</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/nearBlack</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:padding">3dip</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="smallIcon">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of your use of the `TableLayout` while not fully appreciating how it works. What it does is it goes through and figures out how many columns it will have. For each `TableRow` it will put the views in each column starting from the first defined view to the last.

What is happening is that your first `TextView` for artistName is in column 1. The next few `TableRow` only have 1 column. Then you get to the `TableRow` with setDateButton which creates two columns. Now all the other views previously assigned will be in column 1 with a column 2 after them which would be as wide as `editDate` if they had another view.

As a result `setDateButton` is now as wide as your `artistName` `TextView` and since you are using `android:drawableRight` the image is being placed to the right side of the `Button`.

You're going to need to adjust [`layout_column`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) and [`layout_span`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) values to adjust the layout. Alternatively, I would suggest removing the `TableLayout` and using the `RelativeLayout` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `Button` and `TextView` with a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Including an explanation of why the proposed answer would help the asker solve their question is beneficial to not only the asker but to future people who may stumble across this post trying to solve the same problem.